# Converting an octal number to decimal number using char only

Tags: c++, input, inputstream, stdin, getchar

I am new here and new to c++ as well.

I just started my first year at school and I have been given an assignment in which one of the questions is to convert an octal number to a decimal number using Char only.

The task is to create a program that receives chars from the user and where the length of the number is not known in advance. The user should press `'\t'` in order to start calculating to a decimal number.

I don't really understand how it works.Because if I code a simple algorithm such as:

```
char ch;
cin<<ch;

cout>>ch>>endl;
```

and I give it `67`, it will print `6` only. That means that it reads every char separately, doesn't it?

Could someone please help me understand it by showing me the algorithm for this problem or explaining to me how char works?

Thanks a lot
Coral

Comment: You need a `string` of characters, not just a single `char` variable.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Show us what you have so far. "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand about this. Yes, if you read a `char`, it will read a single `char`. What is your question?

Comment: *"The user should press "'\t'" in order to start calculating to a decimal number."* - That's a strange requirement, because in standard C++, you cannot detect a key press directly; you have to wait until the user presses the Enter key. Are you sure your teacher really means `'\t'` and not just Enter?

Comment: Sorry, I mean  enter. Next to it it says '\n'

Answer (score 0):

You will get enough info on how to read from stdin char by char.

please go through this link.
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

 string input = "";

 // How to get a string/sentence with spaces
 cout << "Please enter a valid sentence (with spaces):\n>";
 getline(cin, input);
 cout << "You entered: " << input << endl << endl;

 // How to get a number.
 int myNumber = 0;

 while (true) {
   cout << "Please enter a valid number: ";
   getline(cin, input);

   // This code converts from string to number safely.
   stringstream myStream(input);
   if (myStream >> myNumber)
     break;
   cout << "Invalid number, please try again" << endl;
 }
 cout << "You entered: " << myNumber << endl << endl;

 // How to get a single char.
 char myChar  = {0};

 while (true) {
   cout << "Please enter 1 char: ";
   getline(cin, input);

   if (input.length() == 1) {
     myChar = input[0];
     break;
   }

   cout << "Invalid character, please try again" << endl;
 }
 cout << "You entered: " << myChar << endl << endl;

 cout << "All done. And without using the >> operator" << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: don't solve the homework questions, just help as little as possible.

Comment: You are right. That's the reason I posted a generic input read solution. He needs to customize it further. ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help. The thing is that they  dont want us to use string. only char.. now I coded this,but I got an error for the "while"  can anyone tell me why?
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
 int decimal = 0;
 char octal;
 cout << "Please choose an octal number you would like to convert into a decimal number:" << endl;
 while (octal != '\t');
 {
  octal = getchar();
  if (octal >= '0' && octal <= '7') {
   decimal += (octal - '0'); // next line
   decimal *= 8;
  }
 }
 cout << "The decimal number is: " << decimal / 8 << endl;
}

Comment: Use char array. Instead of string,  char[20], something like that.